# Stack around variable was corrupted (Converting long long to byte array)

Tags: c++, nvcc

When it gets to the end of this function, it bombs with a "Stack around variable was corrupted" for variable keybytes2.  I am not sure as to what I am missing as to why this is a problem.  I am using the NVCC compiler.

```
char keybytes2[7];
long long unsigned lkey;

lKey = 32428228256948131;

//convert long long to byte array
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    keybytes2[i] = ((lkey) >> 8 * i) & 0xFFu;
}
```

Comment: You just invalidated all the answers and ruined the reproducibility of the bug. I'm reverting your edit. If you can produce a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then great, otherwise this should be closed.

Comment: You ought to re-ask a question with the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

```
char keybytes2[7];
```

This only allocates 7 bytes, not 8. But in the loop you access `keybytes2[7]`, i.e. the eighth byte of the array. This is an out-of-range access and thus undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  It is keybytes2[8] and it is still creating the error.

Comment: Ill create a new question... This one got invalidated by my typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your array `keybytes2` only contains elements from 0 to 6.

Your loop is attempting to write to `keybytes2[7]`. That is *undefined behaviour* and, in your case, is manifesting itself by corrupting your stack.

The remedy is to replace with `char keybytes2[8];`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  It is keybytes2[8] and it is still creating the error.